# vi tab completion not working

Tags: autocomplete, vi, permission-denied

I'm trying to view the contents of files in `/var/lib/php5/sessions`, directory in which I have no permissions to do `ls`, so I have to use `sudo ls` to see all those files with long names, I would like to make tab completion work when I type `sudo vi longfilename`.

I have tried starting vi and execute `:e` or `:edit` but it doesn't work either, when I press tab all that it shows is `^I`.

I don't want to use the mouse to copy and paste that long name to execute vi, that's a workaround I don't like.

Answer (score -1):

As your sudo authentication take place after completing the command line, I see no way so have sudo rights during typing the command line other than starting the shell with sudo.

Workaround without mouse:

```
sudo vi `sudo find /var/lib/php5/sessions -name *patternOfLongFile*`
```

Maybe define an alias `sudovi` for that

Comment: it works but, is there any way to make linux autocomplete/suggest file name by pressing tab or whatever key?

Comment: @Ivanzinho You can't make the shell autocomplete for you since it's running "as you" and therefore doesn't have access to the directory listing.

Comment: Hopefully not! The shell shouldn't be able to suggest filenames in unaccessible directories before you authenticate as sudoer. Doing `sudo vi` and then open the file from `vi` will work, if your `vi ` supports tab completion (`vim` does. Please note the different behaviour for multiple matches).

Comment: Having vi running as sudo I definitely can not make it autocomplete using :e or :edit

Comment: But vim does, believe me! What's wrong about vim?

Answer (score -3):

**vi** doesn't do tab-completion.  vim (and other [vi-clones](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.faq.html#vi_clones) such as elvis, vile) do this.  If you happen to be using a machine with vim installed (and if it's not a "minimal" configuration), then you could use vim in your command rather than "vi".

Comment: Some distributions (e.g., Debian, red hat) install vi as an alias (rh) or symlink (Debian) to vim; so it is equivalent in those cases...

Comment: That still doesn't make vim "vi", and your comment is not constructive.

Comment: Neither is your answer... the difference between vim and vi is small enough for a novice user that it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Apparently you're incorrect as well.  Otherwise, OP would not have asked the question.